# Измение размера "Label" при наведении на нее курсором

Tags: c#

Как изменить размер "Label" при наведении на нее курсором? (То есть при простом наведении курсором без нажатия.)

И по возможности, можно привести код работы или ссылку для более высокой понятности?

Answer (score 2):

Вот как вариант

```
private void label1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 17, FontStyle.Italic);
}

private void label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Italic);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Установите свойство AutoSize в false, отлавливайте событие MouseEnter и MouseLeave и в обработчике этих событий изменяйте размер

Comment: можно привести код работы или ссылку для более высокой понятности?

Comment: не верно, как ты поменяешь размер лабела?

Comment: Как у обычного контрола. Только вот что автору вопроса все-таки надо? Размер лейбела или размера шрифта менять? Если шрифта, то ответ Вам уже дали. Если же все таки именно размер лейбела, то так как я описал